# youtube html5 iframe embedding fails in IE, yet I can still watch youtube videos?

Tags: flash, html, youtube, embedding

I'm working on making youtube video embedding script compatible with browsers that do not have flash installed. Here's what happened:

My IE browser does not support FLASH or HTML5. So when I used youtubes iframe API library to load the embedded video, it failed (understandable). Yet, I'm still able to watch videos on Youtube.

How is that possible - and what can I do in the event that the user is using a browser that supports neither HTML5 nor FLASH?

Thanks!